# Vb.net Linq Group by Sum multiple columns

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by, sum

I just want to sum total issues and bays by the month.

My query

```vb
Dim ShippedJobsFromCola = (From J In AllJobs)
    .GroupBy(Function(F) New With {F.ShipDate.Value.Date.Month})
    .Select(Function(X) New With {
        Key .MM = X.Key,
        Key .TotalIssues = X.Sum(Function(G) G.TotalIssues),
        Key .TotalBays = X.Sum(Function(G) G.Bays)
    })
```

I was expecting the below output

```
MM   TotalIssues    TotalBays
1      Number       Number
2      Number       Number
3      Number       Number
4      Number       Number
5      Number       Number
```

But it's not grouping by month. I just get same month repeated number of times.
What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: The grouping type should have `Key`, not the result type. Side note: you probably should group by Year also.